# (using viewport) ipad scaling works but not iphone, or vice-versa

Tags: html, iphone, ipad, viewport

I've unfortunately hit a brick wall on my web design.

Using  allows me to successfully pick up the special mobile css, but this has ipad leave a blank space on the right of the page (i've read that it thinks it's less than what it can really be). I can correct this also in the viewport settings:

but that then means it doesn't pick up the css:
(ie
ink rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/about-mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-width:481px)">

any help that anyone can offer would be so gratefully appreciated
best wishes
paul

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it :-) what's needed is to use php to pick up the browser:

1003, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">device-width">

this is so useful towards responsive design - we can pick specify for any kind of browsing equipment with it, it seems. I hope this is useful to others :-)

Comment: that didn't seem to copy through ok. the code is:  <meta name="viewport" content="width=<?php if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')){ ?>1003, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"><?php } else { ?>device-width"> <?php } ?>